# Sonar error Fail to purge data with Sonar 3.7 and MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, jenkins, sonarqube

I call from Jenkins the Sonar runner and then the following error occurs:

```
Fail to purge data [id=1]
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Prepared or callable statement has more than 2000 parameter markers.
### SQL: delete from dependencies where from_snapshot_id in 
...
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Prepared or callable statement has more than 2000 parameter markers.
```

Does any one knows a workaround of this error (Sonar bug).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this is known issue which should be quickly fixed but for the time being there is no workaround : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4586 expect to downgrade to SonarQube 3.6.